# Плагин jQuery UI tabs, внешняя ссылка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Почему не работает внешняя ссылка на другие сайты?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#cont').tabs();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Первая</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Третья</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Видать потому что функция `tabs()` вешает свой обработчик события на клик по ссылкам, парсит их для якорей например и предотвращает дефолтное поведение далее.

Comment: @SLy_huh там суть плагина в том, что он указанные ссылки показывать должен :) загружать контент через ajax и показывать как-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто табс вешает свои условия на элементы. Так это работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cont').tabs();
    $('#cont a').on("click",function(){
     $('#frame').src = $(this).attr('href');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div id="cont">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Первая</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Третья</a></li>
     </ul>
  <iframe width="400" height="400" name="panel" id="frame"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: А можно сделать чтобы ссылки открывались непосредственно в панели?

Comment: я добавил iframe, только яндекс не открывается в iframe

Answer (score 1):

Потому что [CORS](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), а точнее  [Same Origin Policy](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) не позволит получить данные с чужого сайта.

Можно попытаться использовать iframe'ы, но серьёзные сайты и это не позволят.